# Jenkins release creates branch origin/origin/master (Jenkins GIT plugin + Git Parameter Plug-In)

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I've configured my Jenkins build to use "Git Parameter Plug-In" to select a branch to build. That works like a charm. Hovewer, when I release the project and select "origin/master" branch, maven creates "origin/origin/master" branch and updates POM version on that branch. The "origin/master" branch stays intact. I have configured "Jenkins GIT plugin" with the selected branch variable on follwoing fields:

- Branches to build
- Additional Behaviours/Check out to specifc local
  branch

Do you have any idea how to force Jenkins to do release updates on selected branch using "Git Parameter Plug-In"?

Comment: I have the same problem. 
"Additional Behaviours/Check out to specifc local branch" creates "origin/master" witch then is check in to "origin" and results in "origin/origin/master"

But without that behavior It is not able to build

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the solution in a [blog](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/S7Ugsn8LJuo/zWMKXVxdEAAJ).

**Solution:**

1. delete"additional behavior": "checkout to specific local branch"
2. add "Pre-Build Step" Shell script:

   # checkout to a local branch using the remote branch name
   LOCAL_GIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH/*//}
   git rev-parse --quiet --verify ${LOCAL_GIT_BRANCH} && git branch -D ${LOCAL_GIT_BRANCH}
   git checkout -b ${LOCAL_GIT_BRANCH} ${GIT_COMMIT}

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Maven receiving the branch name as `origin/master` from jenkins depending how the build was configured.

To fix, configure the "Check out to specific local branch" step to an empty value.,  that will strip the `origin/` prefix somehow. This was introduced as a workaround in Jenkins somewhen around 2016.

[image: screenshot]